# Do ruby class variables get cleared between Rails requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

For a caching mechanism for my Rails app I am setting a class variable in an instance method which is then later accessed in a class method. This works, but I'm a bit paranoid that there could be a memory leak. Therefore does anyone know if Rails @@class variables are cleared between requests? I have tried this out (on my local development environment), but you never know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They dont get cleared if you have `config.cache_classes = true`, which is generally the case in production.

Answer (score 3):

Using class variables is not very good idea because you might have more than one concurrent Rails process(and each process will not share class variables with others).

Consider using some built-in mechanism for caching (using memcached or something else).